# Laravel 5.1 how to attach the Order to a User using Pivot Tables?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1

So i am trying to build a structure where One User can have Many Orders and One order has 2 Users(eg: the customer and the employee servicing that order).

This is my migrations:

Orders to Users:

```
Schema::create('order_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->integer('order_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('order_id')->references('id')->on('orders')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Order:

```
Schema::create('orders', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');

        $table->string('boostFrom')->nullable();
        $table->string('boostTo')->nullable();
        $table->string('numGames')->nullable();
        $table->decimal('totalPrice');
        $table->string('ipnStatus');

        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Users:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password', 60);
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

I have not set relationships yet since i test with them already in my User and Order Models. But when i try to attach the Order to User using:

```
$user->order()->attach(4);
```

I get an error relating to Builder.php saying attach() does not exist, but i was following the laravel 5.1 docs to try to attach the order.

Could you please let me know how i should structure everything so when an order is created then i can attach that to a user.

Thanks

As Requested:

```
class Order extends Model
{
    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'orders';

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\User');
    }
}


class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, CanResetPasswordContract, HasRoleAndPermissionContract
{
    use Authenticatable, CanResetPassword, HasRoleAndPermission;

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'password'];

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];

    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public function orders()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Order');
    }

}
```

Error in Tinker:

```
>>> $user->orders()->attach(4)

BadMethodCallException with message 'Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::attach()'
```

Comment: Could you please post the code from your `User` and `Order` models.

Comment: I just added that now

Comment: Infact i have tried a few things using tinker but i havent been able to add anything into my Order_User table.

Comment: Models look fine, could you please also edit the question to include the full error message you're getting (a full stack trace would be even better if possible). Also, not sure if that's a typo in the question or an actual typo in your code (but I'll point it out anyway): `$user->order()->attach(4);` should be `$user->orders()->attach(4);`

Comment: How do i do a stacktrace?

Comment: You should find that in the log file located in `storage/logs/laravel.log`.

Comment: Never mind, I've figured out the problem and posted an answer. The name of the `hasMany` relation can trick you sometimes :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `belongsToMany`, instead of `hasMany`, since you have a **[many-to-many](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)** relationship. The `hasMany` is used to define a **[one-to-many](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)** relation. So you should have this:

```php
// Order.php
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\User');
}
```

and this

```php
// User.php
public function orders()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Order');
}
```

Comment: Ill give this a shot, is the way i used for the tinker correct to attach the order to user?

Comment: Yep, `$user->orders()->attach(4);` should work just fine (assuming of course there's a role with id `4` present in the database :).

Comment: I am still getting a BadMethodCallException with message 'Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::attach()' in tinker?

Comment: Try restarting tinker.

Comment: I still have no clue whats wrong its like the attach() does not exist? even after dump-autoload

Comment: Just to rule out tinker as the source of the issue, try setting up a simple route definition in your app and try the code there.

Comment: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::attach()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88261/discussion-between-elevant-and-bogdan).

Comment: the attach() method only works with many to many relationship table. correct me if i'm wrong